# Basic Solidity coding efficiency question

Tags: solidity

Q1: Outside of readability, is there any reason to prefer

```
x += y;
```

vs

```
x = x + y;
```

Q2: When I have an equation that involves several variables, such as

```
x += y / z * 100 / k + 7;
```

I often feel like I should write

```
x += ((y / z * 100 / k) + 7);
```

just to be sure everything is calculated correctly. If I'm sure my algebra is correct, is this just paranoia?

Comment: Q1. I tested it with a small contract and there is no gas gains. Therefore i assume no reason other than readability.     
Q2. I would always use Brackets rather than depending on solidity getting it in the right order (Don’t sleep in the cemetery, and complain from nightmares)
hope someone give a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Outside of readability, is there any reason to prefer

The only real difference in general programming languages between `x = x + ...` and `x += ...` is that `x += ...` will modify the value in place. But solidity doesn't support the syntax required to meet the edge cases so there is no difference in your case as far as I know.

Even though readability is clearly a very important factor (see [this](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1184#issuecomment-271423201)).

> Q2: When I have an equation that involves several variables, such as...

You might be interested in the [operator's precedence](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.8.13/docs/cheatsheet.rst#order-of-precedence-of-operators) in solidity.

Parentheses have a precedence level of `1`, Multiplication and Division have a precedence level of `4` while Addition is at `5`. Ties should be evaluated from left to right.

In your example, you can remove all the parentheses and still have an evaluation order equivalent to (parentheses are just here to emphasize the evaluation order) :

```
x = x + (((y / z) * 100) / k) + 7;
```

You only really need parentheses if you want a lower precedence operation to be computed before a higher one. That being said, parentheses, however useless, may also help other people read and understand your computation.